# Keycloak remove url fragments after login

Tags: url, wildfly, redirect, keycloak

I'm struggling with Keycloak for what seems a simple problem and, after reading a lot of stuff about the subject, nothing solved my problem yet.

The problem is that I call a url with fragment like http://hostname:8080/somewebui/#!builder/site.com:manager:manager/1.0.0/hostname=anotherhostname.
The fragment after the # allow me to pre-fill fields on the site so that the user has just to click on a button to save the data.
The site is protected by Keycloak.

If I'm already logged on the site and I call this URL, it work fine, the site opens and the requested fields are filled, it's perfect.

On the contrary, if I'm not yet logged on the site (most usual case), the login page managed by Keycloak is displayed asking to enter credentials, which is normal.
But after I successfully enter the credentials, Keycloak redirect me to http://hostname:8080/somewebui/, without the fragment.

My question is therefore simple, how can I said to Keycloak to keep the fragments after a login ?

Thank you in advance,

Seb

Comment: what Keycloak version do you use?

Comment: I use Keycloak 4.5.0.Final.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2

> The endpoint URI MUST NOT include a fragment component.

So fragment in redirect URI can't be supported if the standard is implemented correctly.